# Convert finite automata to regular expression

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am trying find the regular expression that describes the finite automata in the image below.

Given the following finite automata [image: Finite Automata]

which of the following regular expressions describes the same language as the automaton.

- (ab)+c*d+
- a+b+c*d+
- a(ba)*bc*dd*
- [ab]+c*d+
- a(ba)*bc+d?d+
- (ab)+c+d*

I tried converting it to a regular expression and I got (ab)*ac*dd*, which is not among any of the options. Could someone help me select the correct answers?

Comment: `I got (ab)*ac*dd*` how did you get the a between b and d? (`dd*` is fine, depending on context/definition, `d+` is a shorter version thereof.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your regular expression. The correct one is $(ab)^*ab c^*dd^*$ (notice that after reading $(ab)^*$ you are in state $A$ and that the edge from $B$ to $C$ is labelled $b$).

This can be rewritten as $(ab)^+ c^*d^+$ since $(ab)^*ab = (ab)^+$ and $dd^* = d^+$.

Another equivalent expressions is $a(ba)^*bc^*dd^*$ since $(ab)^+ = a(ba)^*b$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know any website where I can learn the equations you used to rewrite the expression?

Comment: No, sorry. What I used is just the definition of "plus". If $E$ is a regular expression then $E^+$ is defined as $EE^*$ (or equivalently $E^*E$). The equality $(ab)^+ = a(ba)^*b$ follows from the fact that both expression correspond to words with $k \in {2,4,6,\dots}$  alternations of "a" and "b". Therefore $(ab)^+ = ab(ab)^* = (ab)^*ab = a(ba)^*b$.